# Error when accessing an Excel workbook from within a parallel loop

Tags: excel, matlab, parallel-processing, activex, file-access

I am using MATLAB to write to an Excel file with Macros in them, and then reevaluate the file and extract the Macro results using `xlsread`. The code works fine with only one worker. However, if I use `parfor` and use a second worker, MATLAB gives the error message as below. To be rigorous, I have created a second Excel file for the second worker and use `t = getCurrentTask(); t.ID;` to instruct the workers to work on their arranged excel file.

> Error using xlswrite (line 226)
>
> Invoke Error, Dispatch Exception:
>   Source: Microsoft Excel
>   Description: Microsoft Excel cannot access the file
>   'C:\Users-----\D0481000'. There are several 
>   possible reasons:
>   • The file name or path does not exist.
>   • The file is being used by another program.
>   • The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.
>   Help File: xlmain11.chm
>   Help Context ID: 0
>
> Error in extractFromExcelExpress (line 249)
>      xlswrite(filename,writtenIn,sheet,'B23');

This happens randomly. I did try to change the folder of the excel files and it starts to work for hours but ultimately stops. I did clear all the add-ins in Excel and I did put the corresponding folder to the excel trust locations.

- The Excel version: 2016
- The MATLAB version: R2017a

Comment: You're trying to open (and write to) the same file simultaneously from multiple workers... this will cause errors for the same reason that trying to do this manually would

Comment: Thank you Wolfie! However, I am sure I am using 't = getCurrentTask(); t.ID;' to make sure that each worker just works on the same file.

Comment: That's exactly my point, if all workers are writing to a single file then you get conflicts, as elaborated on in Dev-iL's answer... The real solution here is to rewrite the Macro in MATLAB - this will speed things up many many times since `xlsread` and `xlswrite` are terribly slow, throwing a `parfor` at the problem is not the answer.

Comment: Thank you Wolfie again. I think I made a typo in my last comment. In each process inside the parfor, I use t = getCurrentTask(); t.ID; to find out which worker is working on the process. Say t.ID==2, then it is worker 2 working on it and I then let worker 2 to use file #2.

Comment: I think your advice on changing the Macro is a good one. It is a bit beyond my experience but I will try when I got some time for it! Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a typical race condition issue caused by multiple processes requiring exclusive access to the same file. The basic idea is that one process still hasn't closed the file when another tries to open it, and you only get errors *sometimes* because these issues don't always occur (see also: [Heisenbug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug)).

Here are several suggestions regarding what you can do (in decreasing order of what makes sense to me):

- Try redesigning the code such that only one process ever accesses (read **OR** write) the file at a time. This is called a "[critical section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section)". The easiest way to achieve this in MATLAB is by having the `xlswrite` code outside the `parfor`. If you're having a hard time implementing this while keeping the `parfor`, simply save all intermediate result to a workspace variable, and write it to disk when the computations are done.
- You might be able to share the ActiveX object between the processes (I've never tried this, and can't say for sure that it's possible), using the same approach as in [`xlswrite1`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10465). Essentially it doesn't try to open and close the file between writes, so the situation where one process still hasn't closed it where another tries to open it cannot happen.
- Find a way to use the [`Workbook.MultiUserEditing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-multiuserediting-property-excel) property. This is possibly related to the previous suggestion.
- Use the fastest storage available. You can use a [RAM drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_RAM_drive_software), and put your Excel file there, so that you could at least avoid any slowness caused by using a network drive, an HDD, or even an SSD.
- If all else fails, surround the `xlswrite` statements with a `while true, try, xlswrite(...); break; catch, pause(0.01); end, end`. This *will* slow the code down but at least it will finish eventually.

Comment: Thank you Dev-iL. For the first point, I think it won't work since the 'xlswrite' step is the main thing I want to accelerate with parfor so it has to be in the original way.

Comment: For the second point, the fact that I need to reevaluate the form after writing to it will hinder this advice from working. I will try the third and come back. Thanks again!